# How can I remove OU rules from a client temporary

Tags: windows-networking

I made a domain named "Blocked" in Windows Server 2016 and created a OU for those clients that have no access to USB or DVD Drives. The problems is that if I bring one of these clients out of OU temporarily, it still has no access to DVD Drive.

Can you help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran any Group Policy troubleshooting tools yet? GPUPDATE, GPRESULT, etc? These should shed some light into where the setting is being blocked.

Comment: yes, i already tried gpupdate and gpupdate /force but didn't help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Part of Supser User (and the Stack Exchange network)'s way of showing what you have tried is to edit your question to include that information. What did your GPRESULT show?